# SuiteScript INVENTORY_BALANCE search throwing UNKNOWN error

Tags: suitescript2.0

I am trying to get a balance of all stock in a location. My script is as such8

```
    var colItem = search.createColumn({
        name : 'itemid',
        join : 'item'
    });
    var colLocationName = search.createColumn({
        name : 'name',
        join : 'location'
    });
    var colOnHand = search.createColumn({
        name : 'onhand'
    });

    var filterLocation = search.createFilter({
        name    : "name",
        join    : "location",
        operator: search.Operator.ANYOF,
        values  : location.name
    });

    var searchResults = search.create({
        type : search.Type.INVENTORY_BALANCE,
        filters : [filterLocation],
        columns : [colItem, colLocationName, colOnHand]
    });
```

When I run this search I am presented with the following error

```
{
    "type": "error.SuiteScriptError",
    "name": "UNEXPECTED_ERROR",
    "message": null,
    "stack": [
        "getRange(N/searchObject)",
        REDACTED
    ],
    "cause": {
        "type": "internal error",
        "code": "UNEXPECTED_ERROR",
        "details": null,
        "userEvent": null,
        "stackTrace": [
            "getRange(N/searchObject)",
            REDACTED
        ],
        "notifyOff": false
    },
    "id": "5ae63ab8-2d5b-4cbc-95ee-99aecad08dd6-2d323031392e31312e3235",
    "notifyOff": false,
    "userFacing": false
}
```

The stack trace only mentions our file names.
I am assuming this has something to do with the way I have created my search, but I don't see a problem with it.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was here

```
var filterLocation = search.createFilter({
    name    : "name",
    join    : "location",
    operator: search.Operator.ANYOF,
    values  : location.name
});
```

location.name cannot have a searh operator of anyof. I changed it to IS and it worked